# How do I save custom information about a user on Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase

Using the firebase platform..

I would like to save some custom information about a user once they register.. and just for examples sake, lets say his/her favorite color.

So far when I register a user this is the only meta data I get

[image]

What options are at my disposal to get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1 - Use Custom Claims

You can save additional data to the access token of the user. You can read that data directly from the user in the frontend and also in all database rules. I would recommend to use this for basic auth data like `isAdmin` or `isRole` if there are not much data to save. The reason for that is that it's quite limited in the amount of data you can save. Because it's saved in the token it has to be small so you should not save to much in it. You can find more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims). You should edit this fields by a firebae cloud function using the `admin` sdk.

2 - Use one of the databases

I see it very often and it's quite common in Firebase to store such additional user data into one of the Firebase databases. You can make those 1000% securely by allowing only the user to write and read then or only to read depending on your needs. If you want to save more than just simple data I would recommend this. One reason more is if any other user like `admin` needs that data from another user you would not be able to get it by using the first option. It is also much easier to do it when the user needs to save data for himself and by himself. With the first version you would always need to involve cloud functions.

I very often use combination of both where I save such data like `isAdmin` to the custom claims but all other like `nickname` or some settings like `language` to a database. With the database I can also make it very easy to search through all users when you are an admin.